# Showing Purchase Counts for ALL months - Including 0 purchase months

Tags: sql, oracle, join, left-join

I want to join a complete calendar table, with per user purchasing data to show, for each user, any purchase counts for every month from 2014 to 2017. Some users may not have a purchase until 2016, but I would still want to have the results show 0's for each month up to the first purchase date, as well as any 0's in between months as well.

I can't get the 0 months to be included! I think it's because I'm doing this across many unique users, but it felt like the below code should work.

```
select
    c.fscl_yr_num
    ,c.fscl_month_num
    ,t.user_id
    ,sum(nvl(t.trans_counter, 0))
from
    appca.d_cal c
left join
    transaction_data t
    on c.cal_dt = t.trans_dt
    and t.trans_type = 'Purchase'
    and c.fscl_yr_num in (2014, 2015, 2016, 2017)
group by
    c.fscl_yr_num
    ,c.fscl_month_num
    ,t.user_id
order by
    t.user_id
    ,c.fscl_yr_num
    ,c.fscl_month_num
;
```

Comment: Why do you have the group-by and order-by clauses in the first subquery; and why do aggregation in the second? In fact why do you have subqueries (inline views) at all?

Comment: I'm brand new to sql and taught myself, so I'm sure I have bad habits.

Comment: @AlexPoole Please see my updated code, which removed subqueries, but did not solve my issue. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SUM(NVL(t.trans_counter,0))
```

Comment: what results are you getting?

Comment: So, I'm hoping for each user id, I'll have ~48 lines, 1 for each month 2014-2017, and then a corresponding purchase count within each month, inclusive of 0 months. I'm only getting rows for each user in which there was a purchase count.

Comment: If user has transaction in 2015 but not in 2014, for example, should the user be in that year as well for all months with zero count?

Comment: Correct, I would want a standard set of 48 months for each user, starting from Jan 2014 thru 2017. Even if a user's first transaction was in 2016, I'd want 0's starting from Jan 2014 for everyone. My biggest problem is actually that all the months in between transactions, where they would show 0, are not showing up in the results. I'm trying to calculate things off of all this missing months.

Comment: can you show the result you have from your query above?